# Getting error while using jinja2 selectattr in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have variables as below, (user enters these)

```yaml
 vlanlist:
   - 3
   - 18 
   - 700
   - 57
```

below is what i gather from the devices and output is as follows:

`output5.msg:`

```json
[
    {
        "INTERFACE": "Ethernet1/1",
        "TRUNKING_VLANS": "2-18,20,24,48,52,54,56-66,68,70,72,76,80-82,84,86,88,90,92-94,96-104,108,112,116-127,700"
    },
    {
        "INTERFACE": "Ethernet1/2",
        "TRUNKING_VLANS": "2-18,20,24,48,52,54,56-66,68,70,72,76,80-82,84,86,88,90,92-94,96-104,108,112,116-127"
    }
]
```

**Scenario**: user enter `vlanlist` and I have to check whether `vlans(3,18,57,700)` entered by user is on interfaces Ethernet1/1 - `TRUNKING_VLANS` and Etherent1/2 -  `TRUNKING_VLANS` based on the `vlans` list below is the expected results:

```
vlan 3 - allowed on Etherent1/1,Etherent1/2
vlan 18 - allowed on Etherent1/1,Etherent1/2
vlan 57 - allowed on Etherent1/1,Etherent1/2
vlan 700 - allowed on Etherent1/1
vlan 700 - NOT allowed on Etherent1/2
```

I am trying using `selectattr` to lookup/find `vlanlist` is in each interfaces `TRUNKING_VLANS` :

```yaml
- set_fact:
     vlan_info: "{{ vlan_info|d({})|combine({item : info}) }}"
   loop: "{{ vlanlist }}"
   vars:
     info: "{{ output5.msg|
              selectattr('TRUNKING_VLANS', 'contains', item)|list }}"

 - debug: msg="{{vlan_info}}"
```

Getting error:

> ```
> {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ output5.msg| selectattr('TRUNKING_VLANS', 'contains', item)|list }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ output5.msg| selectattr('TRUNKING_VLANS', 'contains', item)|list }}): 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"}
> ```

Comment: `TRUNKING_VLANS` is not a list, so you cannot use a simple `contains` on it. Then, the error message is self explanatory, contains can compare on string, but `vlans` contains `int`. You should cast them back as `string`

Comment: Also mind that your `contains` is not going to match `3` since it is defined as a range `2-18` in `TRUNKING_VLANS`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε can you share any example or post that i can refer and fix my code, tried googling for a while couldn’t find, thanks

Comment: Fixing your error message is as simple as `{{ output5.msg | selectattr('TRUNKING_VLANS', 'contains', item | string) | list }}`. But this is not going to fulfil your need, since your requirements are not as trivial as you seems to think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the lists, e.g. create the file

```yaml
shell> cat expand_vlans.yml
- set_fact:
    _vlans: []
- set_fact:
    _vlans: "{{ _vlans + range(start|int, stop|int + 1)|list }}"
  loop: "{{ i.TRUNKING_VLANS.split(',') }}"
  vars:
    start: "{{ item.split('-')|first }}"
    stop: "{{ item.split('-')|last }}"
- set_fact:
    vlan_exp: "{{ vlan_exp|d([]) + [{'INTERFACE': i.INTERFACE,
                                     'TRUNKING_VLANS': _vlans}] }}"
```

and iterate the data

```yaml
    - include_tasks: expand_vlans.yml
      loop: "{{ output5.msg }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: i
```

gives

```yaml
  vlan_exp:
    - INTERFACE: Ethernet1/1
      TRUNKING_VLANS: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20,
        24, 48, 52, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 72, 76, 80,
        81, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 108,
        112, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 700]
    - INTERFACE: Ethernet1/2
      TRUNKING_VLANS: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20,
        24, 48, 52, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 72, 76, 80,
        81, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 108,
        112, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127]
```

Then create the info

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vlan_info: "{{ vlan_info|d({})|combine({item: info}) }}"
      loop: "{{ vlanlist }}"
      vars:
        info: "{{ vlan_exp|
                  selectattr('TRUNKING_VLANS', 'contains', item)|
                  map(attribute='INTERFACE')|
                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  vlan_info:
    3: [Ethernet1/1, Ethernet1/2]
    18: [Ethernet1/1, Ethernet1/2]
    57: [Ethernet1/1, Ethernet1/2]
    700: [Ethernet1/1]
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, impressed the way you came up with the answer/solution.